# How can I make my CustomView conform to more than one protocol in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am working on a CustomView which it must conform 2 protocol to start working, my request protocols are: **Hashable** and **CustomStringConvertible**, the issue start where that my CustomView can take one protocol, I tried to feed both but I failed, for sure I am missing something in syntax, need help for correction please.

```
struct SequencePrinterView<T: Hashable, CustomStringConvertible>: View {

    let sequence: Array<T>

    init(sequence: Array<T>) {

        self.sequence = sequence
   
    }

    var body: some View {

        ForEach(sequence, id:\.self) { item in
            
            Text(item.description )
            
        }
  
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper syntax for requiring a generic parameter conform to multiple protocols is to use `&`:

```swift
struct SequencePrinterView<T: Hashable & CustomStringConvertible>: View
```

You can also use a where clause instead of putting the protocol constraints in the angle brackets:

```swift
struct SequencePrinterView<T>: View where T: Hashable, T: CustomStringConvertible

// or

struct SequencePrinterView<T>: View where T: Hashable & CustomStringConvertible
```